# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent.wsgi'

Tags: python, python-3.6, wsgi, gevent, rasa-core

I'm getting the following error while running a `flask` app:

> from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent.wsgi'

gevent is already installed and the requirement is satisfied.

Pip version is 10.11 and Python 3.6.
 OS: Windows 10 x64
 Using Anaconda VM

This same code worked in another machine, so somewhere I am missing configuration, but I can't track/find it.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging
import json
from pprint import pprint
from rasa_core.channels import HttpInputChannel
from rasa_core import utils
from rasa_core.agent import Agent
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUInterpreter
from rasa_core.channels.channel import UserMessage
from rasa_core.channels.direct import CollectingOutputChannel
from rasa_core.channels.rest import HttpInputComponent
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, abort    
def run(serve_forever=True):
#path to your NLU model
interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter("models/nlu/default/current")
# path to your dialogues models
agent = Agent.load("models/dialogue", interpreter=interpreter)
#http api endpoint for responses
input_channel = SimpleWebBot()
if serve_forever:
    agent.handle_channel(HttpInputChannel(5004, "/chat", input_channel))
return agent
if __name__ == '__main__':
   utils.configure_colored_logging(loglevel="INFO")
   run()
```

Answer (score 25):

Try using:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
```

Instead of:

```
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
```

Comment: Above point is correct, but its rasa-core library issue. After upgraded to 0.9 version. Issue was cleared.

Answer (score 6):

The import statement you quoted needs to be updated to:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
```

The gevent.wsgi module has been deprecated and [was removed](http://www.gevent.org/changelog.html#b2-2018-05-03) when gevent 1.3 was released.  Its replacement is the gevent.pywsgi module, which has been around for some time.

It looks like in your case, the rasa-core library you're using is the one with the bad import line.  This was [fixed](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/pull/461) starting in the 0.9.0 release, so you should update that dependency to a newer version.